# Delete line of a text file with batch

Tags: batch-file, text-files, findstr

I saw that in batch, to delete a specific line from a text file, you need to do it with `findstr`that allow you to find your line and then delete it. But is there a way to do it when you don't know the line ? I got another program that fills the file and the batch must delete the first line. Does anyone know how to do it ?

I tried with something thet reads a line from an index and then use what I got with findstr, but it doesn't work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set count=1
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.txt) do (
if !count! equ 1 (set "TIMER=%%a")
if !count! equ 1 (type test.txt | findstr /v %TIMER%)
set /a count+=1
)
echo %TIMER%
timeout %TIMER%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.txt) do (
echo %%a
)
pause
```

It tells me : FINDSTR : wrong command line
(the piece of code for the loop on the lines of the file and find a specific line was found on the internet)

So where is the problem ? Or maybe does someone know something like delete(x) and it deletes the line ? Just something that takes an INDEX... ^^'

(The last for loop is used to check if the line was removed btw)

Thanks by advance for any help !

Comment: The simplest way to reproduce a text file without its first line, _as long as converting contained tabs to spaces isn't an issue,_ is: `@"%__AppDir__%more.com" +1 "test.txt" > "modifiedtest.txt"`

Comment: or `>RemoveFirstLine.txt <test.txt (set/p"="&%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /R "^")`

Comment: @HackingAddict1337: that's genius. You want that to convert into an answer?

Comment: Thanks a lot to both of you HackingAddict1337 and Compo, I got my solution and you helped me ! Thanks again ! ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code mainly doesn't work because the lack of [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028).

But there are easier ways to achieve your goal. If Compo's suggestion (`more.com" +1 "test.txt" > "modifiedtest.txt"`) doesn't work for you (need to keep TABs or need to remove another line than the first one), the following might work for you:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set file=test.txt
set lineToDelete=1
(for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" "%file%" ^|findstr /bv "%lineToDelete%:"') do echo/%%b) > "%file%.tmp
move /y "%file.tmp%" "%file%"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked ! I searched for a good moment but ended up with no solution, you saved me haha !

Answer (score 3):

To remove the first ***n*** lines from a file without converting tabs into spaces:

```dos
@echo off
>RemoveFirstLine.txt <test.txt (
    FOR /L %%N in (1 1 1) do set/p"=" SKIP N lines
    %__APPDIR__%findstr.exe /R "^"
)
```

This works as `FINDSTR` [moves the pointer from STDIN](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=9720#p9720), while `FIND` and `MORE` do not.

Comment: Thanks ! I already got my solution but this is still helpful ^^